# Was Furious 7 filmed unusually early?

Tags: film-techniques, fast-and-furious-franchise

Every time I revisit the *Fast and Furious* movies and think about Paul Walker's death, it confuses me how they had finished most (not all, but most) of the filming in the same fall that *Fast 6* came out, before he died on 30 November 2013. The franchise was on a 2-year pattern:

- *Fast & Furious*, 2009
- *Fast 5*, 2011
- *Fast 6*, 2013
- *Furious 7*, 2015

But by November 2013, they had managed to film most of the 2015 movie, such that they only had to use a few tricks to end the film without Walker. Is that unusually early to have nearly completed a summer 2015 movie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Plans for a seventh installment were first announced in February 2012 when Johnson stated that production on the film would begin after the completion of Fast & Furious 6.
- In April 2013, Wan was announced to direct the film.
- On April 16, 2013, Diesel announced that the sequel would be **released** on **July** 11, **2014**.
- Principal photography began in early September 2013 and stopped in late November after Walker's death.
- Filming resumed April - July 2014.

> *Is that unusually early to have nearly completed a summer 2015 movie?*

No, not when the movie was *originally a 2014 release* movie that started shooting the year before. Seems a standard schedule.

The so-called franchise pattern is not some kind of fixed 'thing'. Production and release schedules are subject to many different factors (talents conflicting schedules for example), and such a 'pattern' is not usually one of them.

Don't forget that in 2011, it was reported that 6 and 7 would be shot back to back with a single story running through both films. By 2012 it was confirmed that 7 would not start filming until 6 had been completed, so the planned shooting schedule was very fast in the first place - and had absolutely nothing to do with a '2-year release' schedule.

*Wikipedia was used for release/production information.*

Comment: A 2014 original release makes sense now, thanks